# If a codebase includes Twitter Bootstrap, should I use it in preference to hand-coding?

Tags: css

A codebase includes Twitter Bootstrap, I can achieve a design for a component without using Twitter Bootstrap classes & elements. I can also achieve the design using Twitter Bootstrap classes & elements, overriding styles that are not applicable (but come with the built-in classes from Twitter Bootstrap). Which approach should I favor?

Comment: If this is not the appropriate place to ask this question. Can anyone point me to a forum that might?

Comment: I hate twitter bootstrap and will always recommend avoiding it, but this is obviously an opinion, and this question will generate such opinions, which means it's not appropriate for [SO].

Comment: I must say I was a little surprised to see `span`s being used in Twitter Bootstrap where I would expect an `<input type="submit" />`, and this spurred my question.

Comment: @Ben Maybe TW Bootstrap issue tracker on Github? or [Twitter Bootstrap Community Forum](http://www.twitterbootstrap.net).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227000/pros-cons-of-switching-to-twitter-bootstrap/14227267#14227267 (popular question/answer, although it probably deserved its closure). TLDR: a lot of good stuff in Bootstrap, but like any framework, it's not without its quirks/learning curve. And it won't solve every problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask other coders you work with. If you're going to rewrite in your own way all the stuff that others are using and getting for free from Bootstrap, you will not make anyones life any easier.

Answer (score 4):

If the project already includes Bootstrap, it would probably be best to stick to the conventions of the project and use Bootstrap.  If you have full control of the project you might want to remove Bootstrap, but either way it would be good to keep things consistent throughout.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to result in very subjective answers, but I'll try to answer as well as I can.

I think it depends on the goals for your project, as well as the target design you have in mind.

If your priority is **quick and low effort**, maybe you want to use Bootstrap. That's where it seems to slot into development - when you don't want to, or can't, spend the time to do a custom job.

**If you're hoping to end up with a project that looks like effort has gone into it**, avoiding the cookie cutter feel you get from a popular visual framework is probably worth the effort.